# There is an extra '[' in my listing caption

Tags: listings

I made a code lisitng:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption={ This is the caption, reproduced from []},captionpos=b,  frame=single,   numbers=left,label={lst:code}] 
if ....%% code goes here
\end{lstlisting}
```

The caption has a '['. I don't know where it comes from or how to remove it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, resulting in your issue. Then we can copy and test your code on our computers to find the error ...

Comment: The listings manual lists that the caption syntax is `caption={[hshorti]hcaption texti}` the parsing of that might be a bit fragile. It worked for me to use `caption={This is the caption, reproduced from {[]}}`

Comment: @daleif Indeed, the errant `[` goes away with `caption={[]This is the caption, reproduced from []}` as well.

Comment: Note that that choice might have consequences.

Comment: thanks. Problem solved it works.